# Does paypal API suport user to user payments on my app?

Tags: html, paypal

Can I use the Paypal API to allow users to send money to other users without leaving my website?

I have a website where users can become friends, much like Facebook. Can I embed a Paypal form that allows users to send each other money directly without leaving my site to Paypal?

So User1 would select their friend User2, and send him money via Paypal. Then the money would go straight to User2's Paypal account.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up payee is a relatively new feature in paypal. Its fairly simple and i found it [here](https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/). When you setup a payment using some parameters like below

```
 {
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer":
  {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  ...
```

Just add a payee object to it.

```
"payee": {
        "email": "paypal-de@paypal.com"
      }
```

You can find more info on payee [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-payee)

Comment: Yes! thank you so much i was digging for this info and couldnt find it.